# How to deal with lifetimes and the borrow checker in Rust with a struct containing data that is owned and referenced?

Tags: rust, struct, lifetime, borrow-checker

I'm new to Rust, and I'm trying to generate code for filling a crossword, and I have an object structure where Puzzle owns both `grid` and `clues`.

`grid` is essentially a 2-D vector of squares. I want to make it so that each clue can contain references to the squares the clue refers to so that I can edit the squares from the clue object. General code structure below.

```
pub struct Puzzle<'a> {
    grid: Grid,
    pub clues: Vec<Clue<'a>>
}

impl<'a> Puzzle<'a> {
    pub fn new (width: usize, length: usize) -> Self {
        let grid  = Grid::new(width, length);
        let clues = grid.empty_clue_set();
        Puzzle { grid, clues }
    }
// methods
}

struct Grid {
    width: usize,
    length: usize,
    gridvec: Vec<Vec<Square>>,
}

impl Grid {
    pub fn new(width: usize, length: usize) -> Self {
        let gridvec = vec![vec![Square::Empty; width]; length];
        Grid { width, length, gridvec }
    }

    fn search_grid_for_clue(&self, mut i: usize, mut j: usize, orientation: bool) -> Vec<&Square> {
        let mut square_vec: Vec<&Square> = vec![];
        // iterates in one direction until it gets to a black square then runs
        square_vec.push(self.grid[i][j]);
        square_vec
    }

    fn empty_clue_set(&self) -> Vec<Clue> {
        let clues: Vec<Clue> = vec![];
        // iterates over puzzle and repeatedly runs
        clues.push(grid.search_grid_for_clue(i, j, true));
        clues.push(grid.search_grid_for_clue(i, j, false));
        clues
    }
}

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub enum Square {
    Empty,
    Black,
    Filled(char)
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub struct Clue<'a> {
    row: usize,
    col: usize,
    squares: Vec<&'a Square>
}
impl<'a> Clue<'a> {
    pub fn new(row: usize, col: usize, squares: Vec<&'a Square>) -> Self {
        Clue { row, col, squares}
    }
```

I keep getting a compilation issue that I really can't understand

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `grid`
  --> src/lib.rs:10:9
   |
9  |         let clues = grid.empty_clue_set();
   |                     --------------------- `grid` is borrowed here
10 |         Puzzle { grid, clues }
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function

error[E0505]: cannot move out of `grid` because it is borrowed
  --> src/lib.rs:10:18
   |
6  | impl<'a> Puzzle<'a> {
   |      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
7  |     pub fn new (width: usize, length: usize) -> Self {
8  |         let grid  = Grid::new(width, length);
   |             ---- binding `grid` declared here
9  |         let clues = grid.empty_clue_set();
   |                     --------------------- borrow of `grid` occurs here
10 |         Puzzle { grid, clues }
   |         ---------^^^^---------
   |         |        |
   |         |        move out of `grid` occurs here
   |         returning this value requires that `grid` is borrowed for `'a`
```

I think it's because clues contains references, but I can't figure out why this is messing with the borrow checker?

It seems like the borrow checker wants me to add a lifetime reference for `Grid`, but all the data is owned by the struct, so I don't know what exactly to do there.

Comment: You are essentially trying to create a self-referential struct. This is impossible to do in safe rust, and is highly discouraged even though it is possible to do using unsafe rust. See answers to the linked question to learn how to express your logical dependencies better in rust.